# PHP7 ZTS with memcached

Tags: php, memcached, zts

I installed `PHP7.0-zts`, but I cannot get the memcached php client to load and show up in `phpinfo()`.

I have tried many ways of installing `php-memcached` and no matter what I do, I cannot get the extension to load. I am running Ubuntu 14.04, and I have also installed `libmemcached-dev`. It does not show up in `php -m` either on the command line.

When I had `php7.0` installed without ZTS, `memcached` and `php-memcached` loaded fine in `phpinfo()` and I was able to use sessions with `memcached` previously.

Comment: I installed pthread library and had to compile php, I had to enable it before compiling it. I hope, you didn't forget to enable memcached before compiling it

Comment: Do you have any reason to use ZTS? If not, continue to use PHP without ZTS. It's also faster.